How many of the $1,000$ positive integers are in this sequence that can't be written as the product of integers from the set ${a_1,a_2,…,a_{n−1}}$?
A sequence of positive integers has $a_1=1$
, $a_2=2$
. For $n≥3$
, $a_n$
is equal to the smallest positive integer greater than $a_{n−1}$
that cannot be written as the product of one or more different integers selected from the set ${a_1,a_2,…,a_{n−1}}$
. For example, the sequence will start ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, …}$. How many of the first $1,000$ positive integers are included in this sequence?
Note: There are $168$ prime numbers less than $1,000$.
I started by thinking that every prime number has to be in the sequence, as it cannot be written as the product of $1$ or more different integers from the preceding sequence. I am unable to continue from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Think about the exponents in the prime factorizations of numbers.  Are numbers of the form $pq$ in the sequence for $p,q$ prime?  How about $pqr$?  Powers of primes?

Then consider the powers of 2 only. Which powers of 2 are in the sequence? Which aren’t?

What is the exact source of this math problem?

The following Python program:
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

seq = [1]  # We are starting with just one list member
lastNumber = 1000 

def isProduct(n, startIndex = 0):
  for i in range(startIndex, len(seq)):
    m = n
    if m % seq[i] == 0:
      m //= seq[i]
      if m == 1 or isProduct(m, i + 1):
        return True
  return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
  for i in range(2, lastNumber + 1):
    if not isProduct(i):
      seq.append(i)    
  print(seq)
  print("Sequence length:", len(seq))

prints the following sequence:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 81, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 121, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 169, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 256, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 289, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 361, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 529, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 625, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 841, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 961, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]
...with exactly 184 items. Actually, writing this program was a bit of a challenge because it relies heavily on recursion. Fortunately, the explanation of the list is much simpler.
So let's try to make sense of this list. Obviously, all primes less than 1000 are present, 168 of them, no need to explain why. On top of that we have number 1 that starts the list so we have explanation for 169 items on the list. We just need to explain $184-169=15$ more:
Look at powers of 2: note that only $2^1=2$, $2^2=4$, $2^4=16$, $2^8=256$ must be on the list. All other exponents of two less than 1000 can be obtained by multiplying some of them. For example: $128=2^7=2^1\cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^4$, $512=2^9=2^1\cdot 2^8$. So we add 3 more numbers to the list (4, 16, 256). 3 more explained, 12 to go...
For the powers of 3 apply the same reasoning: only $3^1=3$, $3^2=9$, $3^4=81$ have to be on the list (note that $3^8>1000$). So we add 2 more numbers to the list (9, 81). 2 more explained, 10 to go.
For the powers of 5, same thing: Only $5^1=5$, $5^2=25$, $5^4=625$ must be on the list. 2 more explained (25, 625), 8 to go.
For the powers of 7: Only $7^1=7$, $7^2=49$ should be on the list, beacuse $7^4>1000$. One more explained (49), 7 to go.
If you repeat the same logic for the next few primes, you will discover the remaining 7 items from the list: $11^2=121$, $13^2=169$, $17^2=289$, $19^2=361$, $23^2=529$, $29^2=841$ and $31^2=961$. The square of the next prime goes over 1000, so we end the process here.
Also note that with the above described scheme of prime powers, you are able to generate all other composite numbers. For example: $600=2^1\cdot2^2\cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2$.
And that's it.

Live demo: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkE9Lw0AQxe%5F7KR4RIanBJh4LexW8iKDgoZZlbSbpSHaS7G7Qjy9Ja9KDt%5Fnzm3kzL9AAjX15AG7wTrCeEKL1kaXBN8cTvsYQ0Qmh5RDhyH2SV60N8XmcQmiURVEoVVENDi%2D%2Dq8ZjTCU%5Fr3mSin6gUWQ7BdSdB4MF3kpD6UrkaEnSQEM2c4CDhswR13C4RaBhzwdojeJMTMx2qy%2DNS2mGtUaJSWm5xuVg3KHM%5FkYBT3H0gjc%5FklqyR9sGUoprGCPWkTHTssQYZ1mMSf754SHHlRmrBteQLl7dwIt4oOHe9j1JlXKmgN6zxHQTaMgRqNfJhyRrPXmlYSQ50mRRE0%2D75Mos9QuvNoTb&lang=python

@PM2Ring Thanks!

@Saša Thank you for your reply, However, I would like a solution without Python and code.

@JonathanXu This answer by Saša fully explains all the items in the list. The Python code just helps to demonstrate that Saša's logic gives the same result as a brute-force search.
